# How to fix "RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread"

Tags: python, multithreading

```
#   Missing Device Handler
    while operation:
        if controller == 0:
            print("Looking for Controller...")
            find_joystick()
            if controller == 1:
                print("Found Playstation Joystick Controller")
                threading.Thread(name="Playstation Joystick Fix", target=playstation_joystick_controller()).start()
            elif controller == 2:
                print("Found Logitech Controller")
                threading.Thread(name="Logitech Controller Fix", target=logitech_controller).start()
            else:
                print("Controller Not Found")
                time.sleep(2)

        if not rov_connected:
            print("Looking for ROV...")
            Connection.thrusterconnect(1)
            if rov_connected:
                threading.Thread(name="rov_movement_fix", target=rov_movement).start()
                print("ROV Connected")
            else:
                print("ROV Not Found")
                time.sleep(2)
```

This gives the error "RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'checks'." when run in a thread. What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Should read `target=playstation_joystick_controller, without `()

Comment: That still does not work and I am getting the same error

Comment: Read through [There is no current event loop in thread](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=There+is+no+current+event+loop+in+thread)